# Loading in additional partials with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, partials

I use ng-view to pull in a partial to page. After that I would like to load in another partial to the page that would be right next to the initial partial that was brought in.

How would I bring in another partial from a angular controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how `ngRoute` was designed, you can only have one `ng-view` per `ng-app` instance.

However, it looks like you are looking for [`ng-include`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) since the routes do not seem to come into play.

Otherwise, to work around the issue of URL routing having only one template, you have two options:

1. Use [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) **Note:** Under heavy development, may introduce breaking changes.
2. Define and use two angular applications which can reuse the controller/service code. However, then the two applications will not be able to share state.